Redirecting the show action within a namescope
In a Rails app, I have the following route.
namespace :masterdata do
  resources :projects do
    resource :approval, only: [:new], controller: "project_approvals"
  end
end

When submitting the masterdata_parameter_approval#new form, a Signature is created by calling the signatures#create action is called.
Since signatures are associated with multiple models, the signatures#create action redirects to the show action of the signed model.
redirect_to params[:signature].signable

Since the projects routes are namespaced, I get an error telling me that project_url doesn't exist.
To solve the issue, I have added the following route:
get "/projects/:id", to: redirect("/masterdata/projects/%{id}"), as: "project"

Which works, but I'm not too fond of it.
Is there any other way to make the redirect (in the signatures controller) work without adding a dedicated route?

You can either call the routing helper explicitly:
redirect_to masterdata_project_path(project)

Use rails routes -c project to get a list of the routes. The name of the routes are on the first column. Add _path or _url to get the actual helper method.
Or you can pass an array to the polymorphic routing helpers to resolve the route helper method name dynamically:
redirect_to [:masterdata, project]

Both have the exact same end result but the later is useful when you want to generalize the code for resuse.

Sice it's namespaces it should be like this
redirect_to masterdata_project_path(@project)

i assume you have an instance of project in your create action called @project

Thanks. The redirect must remain generic; therefore, the path must be derived from params[:signature].signable.
